# First Order Logic(transfering English to Math)

Tags: first-order-logic

I am trying to convert the following statement to mathematical interpretation but I am not sure whether I am true or not. I really grateful if someone can double check it for me. 
 The statement: "The only one Adam knows who drives a sportcar is Ben"
 predicates:                 K(x,y) x knows y
                             D(x,y) x drives y
                             E(x,y) x = y

unary predicate:            S(x) x is a sportcar

Constants:                  a for Adam
                             b for Ben

my solution: 
   Ex.Ey ( K(a,y) and E(y,b) and S(x) and D(x,y) )
   Ex ans Ey are existential quantifier

Comment: Why do you use 'a' if that's used to refer to Adam, who is not referred to in the sentence at all? Also, if $x$ is the sports car, and $y$ the one doing the driving, you need to use $D(y,x)$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed some parts of the statement. The updated version is substituted.